# Update or Insert mysql column

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have simple mySql question similar to SO "Update mysql column"
I have a table table1 with at least two columns columns and a bunch of rows:
[key_col|col_a|col_other]
I want to **update** one column col_a if key_col=number exist or **insert** if not exists. I first must do select or update do insert automatically?

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

What you said: "I want to update if key exists or insert if not exists" is equivalent to the opposite order: "insert if not exists or update if exists", because the 2 cases are mutually exclusive.

First make sure that `key_col` has a unique index (like: primary key). Then this would work:

```
insert into
    `table1`
    (`key_col`, `col_a`, ...)
values
    (123, 234, ...)
on duplicate key update
    `col_a` = 234, ...;
```

At "..." place the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

if key_col is a primary key then do a replace into instead of doing insert into.....replace into will insert if the key does not exist else update if the key exists.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html "REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted" - how change only one field as UPDATE and preserve other field?

Comment: Is it possible to define a composite unique key on all other fields apart from the one being updated

Comment: SO "mysql REPLACE INTO only some fields" - 
INSERT INTO gfs (localidad, fecha, pp)
VALUES ('some_place', '2012-08-05 02:00', 1.6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pp=VALUES(pp);

Comment: yeah....correct.....the some fields would be a combination of primary + non primary and you would only be updating non primary in case primary exists